# How to program with AVRO org.apache.avro.mapreduce interfaces?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, avro

All of my programs are writing with hadoop's new MR1 interfaces (org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce), so I want to use new org.apache.avro.mapreduce of avro too. But it doesn't work for me.

The program takes input of avro data and output the same.
The main idea behind my program is subclassing hadoop's Mapper and Reducer against avro wrapped key/value.
Here is a block of my job driver :

```
    AvroJob.setInputKeySchema(job, NetflowRecord.getClassSchema());
    AvroJob.setOutputKeySchema(job, NetflowRecord.getClassSchema());

    job.setMapperClass(MyAvroMap.class);
    job.setReducerClass(MyAvroReduce.class);

    job.setInputFormatClass(AvroKeyInputFormat.class);
    job.setOutputFormatClass(AvroKeyOutputFormat.class);

    job.setMapOutputKeyClass(AvroKey.class);
    job.setMapOutputValueClass(AvroValue.class);

    job.setOutputKeyClass(AvroKey.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(NullWritable.class);
```

The definitions of MyAvroMap and MyAvroReduce subclasses respectivly are

```
public static class MyAvroMap extends Mapper<AvroKey<NetflowRecord>, NullWritable,
            AvroKey<CharSequence>, AvroValue<NetflowRecord>>{ ... }

public static class MyAvroReduce extends Reducer<AvroKey<CharSequence>, AvroValue<NetflowRecord>, 
                AvroKey<NetflowRecord>, NullWritable>{ ... }
```

The methioned NetflowRecord is my avro record class. And I got running exception

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.apache.avro.hadoop.io.AvroKey
```

By reading hadoop's and avro's source code,
I found that the exception was thrown by JobConf to make sure
the map key is a subclass of WritableComparable, like this (hadoop1.2.1, line759)

```
WritableComparator.get(getMapOutputKeyClass().asSubclass(WritableComparable.class));
```

But the avro shows that AvroKey and AvroValue are just a simple wrapper **without** subclassing Writable* interfaces of hadoop.

I believe that, even without testing, I can get through using old mapred interfaces, but its not what I want.
Can u give me some examples or explaination about programming with pure org.apache.avro.mapreduce interfaces??

Sincerely,

Jamin

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After hard searching, with the help of this patch https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AVRO-593,
I figure out that *each AvroKey and AvroValue wrapper must have a schema definition in the job configuration*.
That's what I missed.

Here I have two options:

1. If remaining the MyAvroMap and MyAvroReduce unchanged, I have to define a schema for CharSequence and declare this schema with AvroJob for Mapper output, such as

   AvroJob.setMapOutputKeySchema(job, <"defined-schema-for-charsequence">);
   AvroJob.setMapOutputValueSchema(job, NetflowRecord.getClassSchema());
2. By changing the Mapper output key/value as Text/AvroValue, I need only to add schema declaration for Mapper output value, like

   job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
   AvroJob.setMapOutputValueSchema(job, NetflowRecord.getClassSchema());

With the mapreduce API, we do not require to subclass AvroMapper and AvroReducer any more. 
Here, I implement option2 without addtional schema definition in my code.

Jamin